# How to pass table name dynamically in linq to sql

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I need your help to resolve this issue.

How to pass table name dynamically in linq to sql in C#.net?

```
public IntPol(DataClasses1DataContext DC, decimal value,string tableName)
{
}
```

`tableName` will change dynamically.

Comment: Look for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-linq; but I am not sure you can change the table dynamic

Comment: You could check out this post for some options:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200778/dynamic-query-using-linq-to-sql

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is going to be possible. At least not using traditional Ling-To-SQL. You could use the L2S Connection object, hard code a T-SQL statement, and pass that to SQL Server. But, in this case, you aren't really using L2S anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly then you could do something like

```
public IntPol(DataClasses1DataContext DC, decimal value,string tableName)
{
  DC = new DataClasses1DataContext("yourConnString");
  var result = DC.Mapping.GetTables().SingleOrDefault(t => t.TableName.ToString() == tableName);
}
```

Or you could also do `tableObject.GetType().Name` but if type is dynamic might have to send `Type tableType` separately.