# Comparison operators not supported for type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[

Tags: linq, any

I feel that I'm missing something basic, but I'm stuck trying to run this line in C#:

```
bool any = myColl.Any(x => x.CalculateActions().Any(y => y == MyActionTypes.Stop))
```

It throws this exception: "Comparison operators not supported for type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyNamespace.MyActionTypes]"

This line of code works fine and returns true:

```
myColl.First().CalculateActions().First() == MyActionTypes.Stop
```

So I at least know that myColl is populated, that CalculateActions for the first item in myColl is populated, and that when CalculateActions has content, its content items are comparable to MyActionTypes.Stop.

Here's info about the classes involved:

```
 1. myColl is defined as an IQueryable<MyClass>
 2. MyClass has a method CalculateActions, which returns an IEnumerable<MyActionTypes>
 3. MyActionTypes is an enum
```

Any ideas why I'm getting the exception? Many thanks for your help!!

Comment: `myColl.SelectMany(x => x.CalculateActions()).Any(MyActionTypes.Stop.Equals)` ?

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, with that change it doesn't compile, error is "No overload for 'Enum.Equals(object)' matches delegate 'Func<MyActionTypes,bool>'.  The following code does compile, but gets the same error as before ('Comparison operators...'): myColl.SelectMany(x => x.CalculateActions()).Any(y => y == MyActionTypes.Stop).

Comment: Aah, I think the issue is that I'm combining Linq to Sql with Linq to Objects. When I try var val = myColl.SelectMany(x => x.GetAvailableActions());, then the error is "Method '...CalculateActions()' has no supported translation to SQL".

Comment: a bit puzzling why `.First` works. Posting the code for `CalculateActions` might help. You could also try `.Count` instead of `.Any` just in case.

Comment: I think .First() works because it forces the sql query to run. Also works with .ToList() or anything else that prevents delayed execution. myColl is the result of a LinqToSql query, and CalculateActions is just a C# method. I think I will have to do a .ToList() on myColl first and then filter in order for it to run. That's ugly since that will pull ALL of myColl from the db when I might only need one item (since I want a .Any query), but seems like that's my only option? I guess the alternative would be hitting the db for each record, so could be even uglier sometimes...

Comment: there are many other overkill options that I am not quite familiar with like hard coding the SQL statement https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200778/dynamic-query-using-linq-to-sql, stored procedure on the DB side, dynamic LINQ https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library, LINQ Expressions, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145753/discussion-between-user756366-and-slai).