# Dynamically set a table name in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've seen this:

[How can you dynamically select a table with entity framework 4.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800770/how-can-you-dynamically-select-a-table-with-entity-framework-4-x)

However I cannot use a base class in my situation. I am looking to create a user group and week sensitive table for auditing, so I cannot know what these will be called prior to them being created at runtime.

So if I login first week of the year, it would be:

`Group1_01_2014`

Is this possible? I've tried to simply change the database name at creation, but I get the standard exception about database migrations.

Thanks.

Edit: Before someone says splitting the database is silly, know that I'm auditing ALOT. The idea is to be able to audit most transactions, store them as long as needed, without severely affecting performance.

Edit2: That said if someone has a better solution I'm all ears.

**Solution**

Ended up using a stored procedure:.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetAuditTableName
(
  @db_code          CHAR (4)
)   
RETURNS CHAR (12)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @wkNo CHAR (2)
    DECLARE @year CHAR (4)

    SELECT @wkNo = REPLACE(STR(DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE()), 2), SPACE(1), '0')
    SELECT @year = STR(DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()), 4)

    RETURN @db_code + '_' + @year + '_' + @wkNo
END

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Audit_Insert]  
  @audi_id_first    NVARCHAR (20),
  @audi_id_second   NVARCHAR (20),
  @audi_by          NVARCHAR (100),
  @audi_on          DATETIME,
  @audi_details     XML,
  @tabn_code        CHAR (4),
  @audt_id          INT,
  @audi_db_code     CHAR (4)
AS  
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @tableName CHAR (12)
    SET @tableName = [dbo].GetAuditTableName(@audi_db_code)

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name=@tableName and xtype='U')
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @createSql NVARCHAR(MAX);
            SELECT @createSql = 'CREATE TABLE [dbo].' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + ' (
                [audi_id]        INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
                [audi_id_first]  NVARCHAR (20) NULL,
                [audi_id_second] NVARCHAR (20) NULL,
                [audi_by]        NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
                [audi_on]        DATETIME       NOT NULL,
                [audi_details]   XML            NULL,
                [tabn_code]      CHAR (4)       NULL,
                [audt_id]        INT            NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.' + @tableName + '] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([audi_id] ASC),
                CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.' + @tableName + '_dbo.tabn_table_name_tabn_code] FOREIGN KEY ([tabn_code]) REFERENCES [dbo].[tabn_table_name] ([tabn_code]),
                CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.' + @tableName + '_dbo.audt_audit_type_audt_id] FOREIGN KEY ([audt_id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[audt_audit_type] ([audt_id])
            )'
            EXEC sp_executesql @createSql
        END

    DECLARE @insertSql NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SELECT @insertSql = N'INSERT [dbo].' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + ' ([audi_id_first], [audi_id_second], [audi_by], [audi_on], [audi_details], [tabn_code], [audt_id])
                         VALUES (@audi_id_first, @audi_id_second, @audi_by, @audi_on, @audi_details, @tabn_code, @audt_id)'
    EXEC sp_executesql @insertSql, N'@audi_id_first NVARCHAR (20), @audi_id_second NVARCHAR (20), @audi_by NVARCHAR (100), @audi_on DATETIME, @audi_details XML, @tabn_code CHAR (4), @audt_id INT', @audi_id_first, @audi_id_second, @audi_by, @audi_on, @audi_details, @tabn_code, @audt_id

    DECLARE @idSql NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SELECT @idSql = 'DECLARE @audi_id INT
        SELECT @audi_id = [audi_id]
        FROM [dbo].' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + '
        WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [audi_id] = scope_identity()

        SELECT t0.[audi_id]
        FROM [dbo].' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + ' AS t0
        WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND t0.[audi_id] = @audi_id'
    EXEC sp_executesql @idSql
END

GO
```

then calling this from C#:

```
    public void AddRecord(Audit record)
    {
        var Id1 = new SqlParameter("@audi_id_first", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        Id1.Value = (object)record.Id1 ?? System.DBNull.Value;

        var Id2 = new SqlParameter("@audi_id_second", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        Id2.Value = (object)record.Id2 ?? System.DBNull.Value;

        var UserName = new SqlParameter("@audi_by", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        UserName.Value = record.UserName;

        var Stamp = new SqlParameter("@audi_on", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        Stamp.Value = record.Stamp;

        var Details = new SqlParameter("@audi_details", SqlDbType.Xml);
        Details.Value = (object)record.Details ?? System.DBNull.Value;

        var TableCode = new SqlParameter("@tabn_code", SqlDbType.Char);
        TableCode.Value = record.TableCode;

        var TypeId = new SqlParameter("@audt_id", SqlDbType.Int);
        TypeId.Value = record.TypeId;

        var DatabaseCode = new SqlParameter("@audi_db_code", SqlDbType.Char);
        DatabaseCode.Value = CallingPrefix;

        this.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC Audit_Insert @audi_id_first, @audi_id_second, @audi_by, @audi_on, @audi_details, @tabn_code, @audt_id, @audi_db_code",
            Id1, Id2, UserName, Stamp, Details, TableCode, TypeId, DatabaseCode);
    }
```

My next struggle is getting it to work with IQueryable OData requests.

**Solution 2**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateAuditTableIfNoneExists]  
  @tableName        CHAR (12)
AS  
BEGIN 
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name=@tableName and xtype='U')
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @createSql NVARCHAR(MAX);
            SELECT @createSql = 'CREATE TABLE [dbo].' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + ' (
                [audi_id]        INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
                [audi_id_first]  NVARCHAR (20) NULL,
                [audi_id_second] NVARCHAR (20) NULL,
                [audi_by]        NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
                [audi_on]        DATETIME       NOT NULL,
                [audi_details]   XML            NULL,
                [tabn_code]      CHAR (4)       NULL,
                [audt_id]        INT            NOT NULL,
                CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.' + @tableName + '] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([audi_id] ASC),
                CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.' + @tableName + '_dbo.tabn_table_name_tabn_code] FOREIGN KEY ([tabn_code]) REFERENCES [dbo].[tabn_table_name] ([tabn_code]),
                CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.' + @tableName + '_dbo.audt_audit_type_audt_id] FOREIGN KEY ([audt_id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[audt_audit_type] ([audt_id])
            )'
            EXEC sp_executesql @createSql
        END
END
```

and on database initialisation make sure the table is present:

```
public class AuditInitialiser : IDatabaseInitializer<AuditContext>
{
    public void InitializeDatabase(AuditContext context)
    {
        if (context.Database.CreateIfNotExists())
        {
            Seed(context);
        }

        var tableName = new SqlParameter("@tableName", SqlDbType.Char);
        tableName.Value = context.AuditTableName;
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC CreateAuditTableIfNoneExists @tableName", tableName);
    }
```

However this only works for me because I am using an API, so is stateless and constructs the DbContext every time. This ensures the table is always present. Wouldn't work if I was doing my working out on a stated system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a huge fan of stored procedures, but this might be a case where you want to use EF 6's (EF5??)'s ability to bind to stored procs.  Then you could pass the table to use as parameter.  See if this helps:  [How to call Stored Procedure in Entity Framework 6 (Code-First)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901419/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-code-first-entity-framework-6)

(you could also perhaps use EntitySQL to solve this)

Comment: Stored procedures seem to map to insert, update and delete but not read. Am I right in understanding if I did this, I would be unable to return the data?

Comment: Suppose I could do raw SQL queries to get the data.

Comment: I believe that you can do a select with a stored proc (supporting procedures that return multiple result sets was a feature of EF 5, so there has to be some support for selecting).  I have not done it myself, though.

Comment: Struggling to actually add the stored procedure in the first place. I'm code first. How would I add a procedure to the database without the sql server manager? Thanks.

Comment: Shoot.  I don't generally use migrations (not against them, just doesn't fit our workflow).  I would typically use sql server manager.  But, have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701608/unique-key-with-ef-code-first/5701702#5701702

Comment: Yeah I'm thinking I will write the procedures to a .sql script and run off that. I just keep thinking there has to be an easier way to run the script that doing a FileRead and pushing to context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand. Will mark this as answer if I get it working tomorrow.

Comment: Good luck!  Either way, let me know how it goes!

Comment: Sad times. I've gotten it working, but EF doesn't like it. It does a concurrency check after the insert and throws an exception, rolling back my changes. `An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.`

Comment: That's weird -- are you doing any data modification, or just a select.  Does that table have a timestamp or rowversion datatype column (SQL Server Timestamp, not just a datetime field)

Comment: I was trying to insert. I've ended up abandoning inserting with the DbSet and instead using ExecuteSqlCommand to call the Stored procedure. Works! Now trying to select the data as ObjectQuery correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure about this Tim, but it might just be that your insert stored procedure needs to return the number of rows that were inserted as its return value --like maybe return @@ROWCOUNT.

Comment: Maybe. In any event I've just realised that all I needed to do in the first place was remove a database initialiser (or make my own implementation) and it allows me to change the table name anytime.